# Tool to identify floating point arithmetic in .NET project

Tags: .net, floating-point

Does anyone have a recommendation for a tool which would allow me to look at source code files and quickly identify if we are doing any arithmetic on floating point data types?

We have a large financial application, and I want to make sure we're not using Doubles for any values that will end up being used in calculations.

Comment: Do a search in solution for double?

Comment: Yep, I've done it.  It won't find properties or variables that are double AND used in a calculation.  I can find a list of all doubles this way, but then I have to manually search for the usage of that variable.  I've never seen a feature that can produce this kind of information for me.  I don't believe Resharper or VS Ultimate can even do this.  I want an intelligent search that will find anywhere a "Double" data type is used in arithmatic...

Comment: Use Reflector.NET's Analyse/Used By feature.

Comment: @user1060500 That's not going to help you anyway. The problem is not just with floating point arithmetic, it's in the storage as well. Just converting to `decimal` before doing the arithmetic and than converting back to `double`/`float` will not really improve much. What would be a legitimate use of floating point numbers in your application?

Answer (score 0):

You could run a search by pattern with Resharper. The pattern would be `$a$ + $b$` and you need to restrict `a, b` to be an expression of one of the floating point types.

This way you'll have to run one search for each operator and type but at least it is a constant amount of work for arbitrarily big code size.

Alternatively, you could write a Resharper plugin (not that hard) or a Roslyn-based search algorithm.

Actually, in your situation it might be a good idea to have a tool flag *any* floating point computations directly in Visual Studio as you code. Resharper can do that. I believe you can create an analysis rule from a pattern search.